# Getting Mac NPAPI plugin to support high resolution windows for retina displays

Tags: cocoa, npapi, macos-carbon, retina

I am working on a project where we have a Mac desktop application that has an NPAPI based browser plugin that can be used to edit it's documents through a browser. The codebase is a mixture of Carbon and Cocoa UI code that is shared between the app and the plugin.

We've recently enabled retina support in the app by turning on the High Resolution Capable flag in the application plist and are in the process of porting the interface over to Cocoa. In the app things are displaying correctly with retina displays but in the plugin none of the windows are drawing in high dpi mode.

The document displayed in the browser window is drawing correctly as I can get the content scale factor using NPNVcontentsScaleFactor and apply it to the layers. The problem is with the extra windows that we create, dialogs and toolbars, which are not being drawn in high dpi mode.

Is there a way to get windows we create in the NPAPI plugin to draw at the high resolution?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have a horrible feeling it's not going to be possible. I can't find any documentation on it. I guess that plugin makers aren't really encouraged to create windows of their own.

Comment: more like "actively discouraged from creating windows of their own"